# TypeORM: Many to Many Relation outputs wrong data with where

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I have 2 tables, `User` and `Race`. `Race` can contain multiple `Users`, so I created a `Many to Many` Relation. I need to get all `Races` where a `user` is member of. Now the problem is, that it doesn't get all users but only the user requesting.

If I remove the `relations: ["users"]` from the `find` method, it works as expected.

### Entities

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({unique: true})
  email: string;
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Race {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User, {onDelete: "CASCADE"})
  @JoinTable()
  users: User[];
}
```

```
export default class RaceRepository {
  public async listRaces(user: number): Promise<Race[]> {
    return await this.entityHandler
      .getRepository(Race)
      .find({where: {users: {id: user}}, relations: ["users"]});
  }
}
```

### Expected Output

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Race 1",
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "user1@app.com"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "user2@app.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### Actual Output

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Race 1",
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "user1@app.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `find` with relations typeorm is creating a query with some `JOIN`s. So, if you have 1 record in `races` table and 2 records in `users` table, the database will construct a new table with `1 x 2 = 2` records.

| user.id | user.email | race.id | race.name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user1@app.com | 1 | Race 1 |
| 2 | user2@app.com | 1 | Race 1 |

And then it will only take the first record as it meets your `where` conditions. After that, typeorm will create its output from this record.

To get this work, you should separate it into 2 queries or use `QueryBuilder`.

```
export default class RaceRepository {

    public async listRaces(user: number): Promise<Race[]> {

        // Find all races of the user
        // We only need ids
        const races = await this.entityHandler
            .getRepository(Race)
            .find({
                select: { id: true },
                where: { users: { id: user } }
            });

        // Create array of ids from output
        const raceIds = races.map((race) => race.id);

        // Get final result with `In` too look through array of ids
        return await this.entityHandler
            .getRepository(Race)
            .find({
                where: { id: In(raceIds) },
                relations: { users: true }
            });

    }

}
```

```
export default class RaceRepository {

    public async listRaces(user: number): Promise<Race[]> {

        // We are joining user column twice
        // I guess entityHandler is a manger
        await this.entityHandler
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .select(["race.id", "race.name"])
            .from(Race, "race")
            .leftJoin("race.users", "userWhere")
            .leftJoinAndSelect("race.users", "user")
            .where("userWhere.id = :id", { id: user })
            .getMany();

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Out of interest, is there any associated documentation to why TypeORM only returns the first entity in this case rather than all of them?

Comment: It feels counterintuitive as you are not asking for users that match the condition, you are asking for races that match the given condition and that happens to use a condition based on users. It feels like all users should be returned as the author stated.